# A docker container produce errors with Apptainer unless in writable sandbox mode

Tags: debugging, containers, sandbox, singularity-container, apptainer

A (confidential) docker container fails on tests when run by Apptainer unless it is in the writable sandbox mode.

I tried `ls \ -tral` I see only `/etc`, `/tmp`, mounted and special folders like `/.singularity.d` being modified in writable sandbox.

Any ideas to correct the issue?